# When working with a nested mongoose schema, how do I bind to it in the DOM with ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angular-ngmodel

I have created a schema using Mongoose which has some nested elements inside it and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to reference it with ng-model. I know the solution is probably staring me right in the face, but I can't figure it out.

Cutting out the additional details, here is the nested part of my schema:

```
var taskSchema = new schema({
  milestones: [{
    date: Date,
    milestone: String
  }],
  notes: [{
    date: Date,
    note: String
  }]
});
```

And here is how I am trying to bind my form

```
<textarea rows="2" width="60" placeholder="Why do you want to {{ task.title | lowercase }}?" ng-model="task.notes.note"></textarea>
```

and

```
<input type="text" ng-model="task.milestones.milestone">
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The `notes` and `milestones` specified in your schema are document arrays, but you are attempting to access them in angular as if they were an object... basically, there is no such property as `task.notes.note` etc

Comment: I just saw that myself as well! Removed the array brackets and it's working great now! Thank you.